# Color formatting of Rows based on input values for a cell

Tags: excel, vba

There is some data in the worksheet, which includes a column for time. Time Range is provided as an Input to format the color of the time cells within that time range. Color formatting of the rows containing those cells is also desired but is not observed in the output. It is to mention that the start time or end time provided as input is sometimes not matching value of any time cell.

Attached is the code and is not giving desired output.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim timeRange As Range

 Set ws = Sheets("Worksheet") 'Name of my worksheet goes here. 
 Set timeRange = ws.Range("D:D")

'input the lower limit and the upper limit of the search range
Dim Start_Time As Variant
Dim End_Time As Variant

Start_Time = InputBox(prompt:="Enter the Start_Time(hh:mm:ss.000)")
End_Time = InputBox(prompt:="Enter the End_Time(hh:mm:ss.000)")


    timeRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
    Formula1:=Start_Time, Formula2:=End_Time

    timeRange.FormatConditions(timeRange.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

 With timeRange.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With timeRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
timeRange.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


 'Loop to format the rows that contains those time values
 Dim Range_Search As String
For Each c In Range("D:D")
If c.Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
    Range_Search = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "H" & c.Row
    ws.Range(Range_Search).Interior.Color = 13551615
End If
Next c
```

Comment: If you build the conditional formatting rule manually via the ribbon (Home/Conditional Formatting/New Rule/etc...), does it work?  If so, what does that rule look like?

Comment: Nothing really happened by doing what you asked.  but when I run my code I do get my time columns highlighted but nothing more than that. Also, the last loop does run but does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The final loop in your code won't work.  You need to change it to:

```
For Each c In Range("D:D")
    If c.Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
        Range_Search = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "H" & c.Row
        Range(Range_Search).Select
        Selection.Interior.Color = 13551615
    End If
Next c
```

I'm not sure what the "Let" is supposed to do in your statement, but it's not necessary.  Also, you need to get the Row from cell c, not just c.

To make this even better, I would reference the cells by the worksheet as this will prevent possible problems from selecting different worksheets:

```
Dim ws As worksheet
Dim timeRange As Range

Set ws = Sheets("mySheet") 'Obviously change this to your sheet name
Set timeRange = ws.Range("D:D")
```

Then replace "Selection." with "timeRange." in your code, so

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
Formula1:=Start_Time, Formula2:=End_Time
```

becomes:

```
timeRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
Formula1:=Start_Time, Formula2:=End_Time
```

Then change your final loop to do something similar:

```
For Each c In timeRange
    If c.Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
        ws.Range("A" & c.Row & ":" & "H" & c.Row).Interior.Color = 13551615            
    End If
Next c
```

Selecting cells is not efficient and can cause problems if something else inadvertently gets selected while you are trying to run the code.

Comment: It did format the time cells and did run the loop but didn't format the rows.

Comment: Try the new edit.  You may have been looping through the wrong worksheet.

Comment: what if you run this code in the immediate window: "ws.Range("A3:H3").Interior.Color = 13551615" does it change row 3 then?

Comment: still not working. I have change everything as advised. I changed all the selections to timeRange and did include the name of  worksheet in timeRange but still it is only changing the time cells.

Comment: Did you run the line I just suggested in the immediate window?  You may need to do "Sheets("mysheet").Rnage("A3:H3").Interior.Color = 13551615" if you are not currently running the macro.  Have you stepped through the code?  Does the ws.Range line get ruN?

Comment: it doesnt do anything even when you change the Range to ws.Range("A3:B3").Interior.Color. It looks like as if it does run the loop and look for something but it doesnt do anything to the worksheet.

Comment: I have also updated the code so that you can have a look at it.

Comment: Step through the code at the loop.  Does the IF condition ever get satisfied to run that line of code?  How many times does it loop through?  Have you done specifically what I asked?  Either use the immediate window to run the code I am suggesting or put the code OUTSIDE of the loop and determine if it works there.

Comment: So It looks like that the if statement is not working. Cause I did put the if statement out of the loop and it didnt give any result and then I put the code from if statement out and it worked.

Comment: Then I would debug.print c.Interior.Color and see try to figure out why it isn't the right value.

Comment: So it turns out that the color format conditions code shows is different then the color the debug code is showing. it turns out to be 16777215. but its still showing some issues. I'll try going through them tomorrow.

Comment: thanks for your help. your code did make things easier. I have post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks to OpiesDad for help.

Basically the format condition color is not recognize by the vba until you add DisplayFormat. before the interior.color command. so something like.

```
For Each c In timeRange
If c.**DisplayFormat**.Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
    ws.Range("A" & c.Row & ":" & "H" & c.Row).Interior.Color = 13551615            
End If
Next c
```